# python transform 1d array of probabilities to 2d array

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have an array of probabilities:

```
l = [0.9, 0.2, 0.4]
```

and I want to make it 2d array:

```
l = [0.9 0.1
     0.2 0.8
     0.4 0.6]
```

What is the best way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea is use [`numpy.hstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html):

```
l = [0.9, 0.2, 0.4]

a = np.array(l)[:, None]

arr = np.hstack((a, 1 - a))
print (arr)
[[0.9 0.1]
 [0.2 0.8]
 [0.4 0.6]]
```

Or use [`numpy.c_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.c_.html):

```
a = np.array(l)
arr = np.c_[a, 1 - a]
print (arr)
```